¿Existe en HTML el color transparente?
Mi pregunta es la siguiente:
¿Existe en HTML el color transparente?
Sé que cualquier color se le puede aplicar transparencia tanto con rgba() cómo con hsla() por lo que cualquier color puede presentar transparencia.
También he buscado en la documentación de la w3schools y no se ve cómo color el transparente como nombre de color.
La duda me surge de ver el código de otros donde lo usaban y me pregunté si estaba bien hecho o mal hecho.
Gracias por vuestras respuestas.


background-color: transparent;




transparent es mismo que hacer rgba(0, 0, 0, 0). Mientras el alfa sea totalmente 0, será transparente. Si es un 0.5 por ejemplo, sería semi-transparente.

transparent entonces es una constante o un nombre de color ¿valido?
En la documentación no lo pone...

Si, es válido creo que en todos los navegadores. Es parte de Opacity/Opacidad, y no solo como transparent. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

El código no está aplicado a ningún elemento por si querías hacer algo diferente

w3schools NO es la documentación oficial, de hecho el sitio tiene mala fama en un amplio sector de los programadores con más experiencia, porque en muchos casos inducía a malas prácticas (no sé como está el asunto hoy, puesto que nunca he usado ese sitio). La especificación oficial de css está en w3.org. Si quieres leer lo que pone sobre trasparent, aquí lo tienes. Usa siempre la fuente original, en vez de irte por los sucedáneos.

Yo es el que uso. Tienen abundante info para todo por eso lo uso. Gracias por tu aporte.

Abundando en el problema sobre w3schools, le dedicaron incluso un sitio llamado w3fools que empezó a indicar todos los errores y malas prácticas del sitio. Ellos mismos dicen que con el tiempo los errores fueron corregidos. Sea como sea, lo mejor es siempre informarse en los sitios que contienen la especificación oficial. El que un sito tenga un buen ranking en los buscadores, no significa que sea el mejor.

@PolFlórezViciana si varias personas te dicen que no te guies por eso, y que mejor uses la documentacion oficial, no seria mejor pensar que realmente ese sitio te esta dando mal la informacion, y lo correcto es todo lo otro???

@A.Cedano antes era peor. Aunque personalmente me gusta más https://developer.mozilla.org/ que tiene referencias a las especificaciones

Sí que existe, y adivina de qué color se ve. Es genial, el mejor color de todos. Hay una historia de un Rey que se mandó a hacer un traje de ese color, supongo que la conoces.

Respuesta corta: Si existe el color transparente y es el equivalente al negro transparente #00000000

En términos físicos el color es un concepto relativo a la luz, por lo que esta pregunta me recordó al Unicornio rosa invisible que es rosa y a su vez invisible. Ya que algo transparente, que por definición no refleja la luz, ¿puede considerarse un color?
En cualquier caso, ese debate fisico/filosofico sobre lo que es un color, no es relevante para nosotros. Aquí lo que nos compete es la programación y en este caso especifico CSS.
Para css, un color es un tipo de datos (tal como puede ser un string o un interger), y en CSS un color incluye el canal alfa (o transparencia). Este tipo color es la representación del color físico y puede escribirse en distintos formatos: rgb, hsl, hwb, rbga lch, etc.
Este tipo color puede usarse en cualquier propiedad CSS que acepte ese tipo como lo es color o background-color
Por otro lado y de forma genérica podemos aceptar que cualquier color que tenga 0 en su canal alfa será transparente, pero existen los:
Colores con nombre
Los colores con nombre (named color) son lo que podríamos llamar un alias a un color en particular. Asi como el color red es equivalente al #ff0000, el color transparent es #00000000 es decir al negro transparente. Por lo que ese color si existe y se encuentra correctamente en la especificación
Como curiosidad, lo colores con nombre no responden a ninguna lógica, son totalmente arbitrarios y mayormente se han incluido por temas históricos. Por ejemplo:

Lo primeros 16 colores provienen de la paleta VGA
El gris osuro (darkgrey) es más claro que el gris(gray), mientras que el rosa claro(lightpink) es más oscuro que el rosa(pink)


"Si existe el color transparente y es el equivalente al negro transparente" -> De hecho, internamente le referencian a veces como transparent-black, siendo el "negro normal" opaque-black. Aunque eso lo encontré en varios documentos del draft, no sé cómo quedó al final. Pero tiene sentido, en realidad es un negro (0,0,0,0) como bien dices :P

@Benito-B tiene parte de la razón ...  según el título de la pregunta "en HTML" no entiendo que tiene que ver  "concepto relativo a la luz" esto está de más, adicional en css color level 3 ya transparent es un color ... según los estándares de los navegadores...

Para entender bien de que estamos hablando, hay que empezar por la física.
El color es una propiedad de los objetos, que está relacionada con la longitud de onda (o su contraparte, la frecuencia) de la luz reflejada por un objeto.
La transparencia, es una propiedad que tienen algunos objetos, de permitir el paso de la luz a traves e ellos.
Como ya estás deduciendo, son dos propiedades totalmente independientes, aunque...
Un objeto que permite que toda la luz lo atraviese (es totalmente transparente) es teóricamente invisible, y si, no puede reflejar la luz, ergo no tiene color, pero entonces porque el estandar dice que la propiedad transparent, equivale a rgb(0 0 0 / 0% )?...
Primero somos humanos, segundo no somos físicos, tercero, buscamos simplificar, cuarto, la funcion que determina la transparencia, espera cuatro valores, porque 0, 0, 0?, no se puede saber, tal vez les gusto, tal vez algún "genio" decidió que lo invisible era negro...
Vamos con una pruebita (si, chiquita, jaja):


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
   <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ejemplo de background-color</title>
  <style>
    /* color rojo 100% transparente */
    .nombre-color {
      background-color: rgb( 255, 0, 0, 0 );
    }

    /* color verde 100% transparente */
    .hexadecimal {
      background-color: rgb( 0, 255, 0, 0 )
    }

    /*color azul 100% transparente */
    .rgb {
      background-color: rgb( 0, 0, 255, 0 );  
    }

    /* color negro 100% transparente */
    .hsl {
      background-color: rgb( 0, 0, 0, 0 )
    }

    /* color vayaasaber 50% transparente */
    .transparente {
      background-color: rgb( 70, 140, 190, 0.5 );
    }
  </style>
   </head>
   <body>
  <div class="nombre-color">color rojo 100% transparente</div>
  <div class="hexadecimal">color verde 100% transparente</div>
  <div class="rgb">color azul 100% transparente</div>
  <div class="hsl">color negro 100% transparente</div>
  <div class="transparente">color vayaasaber 50% transparente</div>
   </body>
</html>



PD: no se les ocurra presentar en un examen de física mis definiciones, no es que vayan a desaprobar... van a ser expulsados!!.
No sé que opinan, pero para mi, el azul 100% transparente es el más lindo!!.
No digan nada, pero el código de la prueba se lo robé al incomparable Francisco IA Lover.
Feliz 2025 para todos, tóxicos incluidos!.

Sigo pensando que todo lo comentado sobre física está de más ... XD

Maestro, Feliz 2025, y si, puede que tengas razón!!!!

Feliz años 2025.

La respuesta es "en HTML antes no, ahora si".
TL;DR
Si nos vamos directamente a la documentacion del estándar de colores utilizado por los navegadores: aquí
Se indica en los comentarios que es un Special Keyword:

Analisemos un poco y profundisemos en las definisiones para poder notar la diferencia:
La propiedad background-color en CSS permite establecer el color de fondo de un elemento. Puedes especificar el color de fondo utilizando nombres de colores, valores hexadecimales, RGB, HSL, o incluso establecer que no haya fondo con el special keyword: transparent.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ejemplo de background-color</title>
  <style>
    /* Usando nombre de color */
    .nombre-color {
      background-color: red;
    }

    /* Usando valor hexadecimal */
    .hexadecimal {
      background-color: #00ff00; /* Verde */
    }

    /* Usando RGB */
    .rgb {
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255); /* Azul */
    }

    /* Usando HSL */
    .hsl {
      background-color: hsl(120, 100%, 50%); /* Verde */
    }

    /* Fondo transparente */
    .transparente {
      background-color: transparent;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="nombre-color">Fondo rojo (nombre de color)</div>
  <div class="hexadecimal">Fondo verde (#00ff00)</div>
  <div class="rgb">Fondo azul (rgb(0, 0, 255))</div>
  <div class="hsl">Fondo verde (hsl(120, 100%, 50%))</div>
  <div class="transparente">Fondo transparente</div>
</body>
</html>



Valores posibles:
Nombre de color: como red, blue, o green. 
Hexadecimal: como #RRGGBB o #RGB. 
RGB: como rgb(255, 0, 0) para rojo. 
HSL: como hsl(0, 100%, 50%) para rojo. 
Special keyword: transparent, aplica un color estándar al elemento con valor alpha 0.
Pero qué hace entonces transparent?
Los special Keyword en el navegador retornan un valor por defecto que depende de cada navegador, en este caso transparent para la mayoría de navegadores es un atajo al color: rgb(0 0 0 / 0%) documentado aquí en donde 0% es el valor alpha aplicando para que sea transparente, que tambien esta explicado aqui
En Ingles:

transparent: The transparent keyword represents a fully transparent color. This makes the background behind the colored item
completely visible. Technically, transparent is a shortcut for rgb(0 0 0 / 0%).
To prevent unexpected behavior, such as in a , the current
CSS spec states that transparent should be calculated in the
alpha-premultiplied color space. However, be aware that older browsers
may treat it as black with an alpha value of 0.
The transparent keyword wasn't a true color in CSS Level 2 (Revision
1). It was a special keyword that could be used instead of a regular
 value on two CSS properties: background and border. It was
essentially added to allow developers to override an inherited solid
color. With the advent of alpha channels in CSS Colors Level 3,
transparent was redefined as a true color. It can now be used wherever
a  value can be used.

en español:

transparente: La palabra clave transparent representa un color completamente transparente. Esto hace que el fondo detrás del elemento
coloreado sea completamente visible. Técnicamente, transparent es un
atajo para rgb(0 0 0 / 0%).
Para prevenir comportamientos inesperados, como en un <gradient>, la
especificación actual de CSS establece que transparent debe calcularse
en el espacio de color con pre-multiplicación de alfa. Sin embargo,
ten en cuenta que los navegadores más antiguos pueden tratarlo como
negro con un valor alfa de 0.
La palabra clave transparent no era un color verdadero en CSS Nivel
2 (Revisión 1). Era una palabra clave especial que se podía usar en
lugar de un valor de <color> regular en dos propiedades de CSS:
background y border. Básicamente, se añadió para permitir a los
desarrolladores sobrescribir un color sólido heredado. Con la
introducción de los canales alfa en CSS Colors Nivel 3, transparent
fue redefinido como un color verdadero. Ahora puede ser utilizado en
cualquier lugar donde se acepte un valor de <color>.

Entonces reafirmamos... transparent no era un estándar de color, es un special keyword, que accede a un valor por defecto, en la actualidad si se le considera un color ya que es aceptado dentro de cualquier tag color.
Recomendación:

Usa https://www.w3.org/ para validar la informacion tecnica y estándares implementados canónicamente por la web.
Usa https://developer.mozilla.org/ como sitio de documentacion para los principales estándares html, CSS y Javascript que soportan los Navegadores actuales, ya que este sitio es mantenido por las empresas y desarrolladores relacionados a la web, (Mozilla Foundation y Mozilla Corporation, Contribuidores de la comunidad, Empresas asociadas: Google, Microsoft y Samsung)


No es que exista el "color transparente" como tal, es una propiedad que admite la regla background-color. Esto es opcional ya que es el valor que toma por defecto, tal como puedes observar en el siguiente ejemplo... La etiqueta <p> tiene aplicado el fondo transparente pero no hace diferencia alguna si no se aplica.


body {
  background-color: coral;
}

p {
  background-color: transparent;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The background-color Property</h1>

<p>
To add a background color you can use color names or values. Values can be of type HEX, RGB, RGBA, HSL, or HSLA.
</p>

</body>
</html>




En la w3schools no aparece esto cómo constante o nombre de color puesto que cualquier etiqueta es transparente hasta que no se indique lo contrario.
Ponerle transparent a esa propiedad es lo que cuestiono. Gracias por tu respuesta.

w3schools no es la documentación oficial, es más bien un sitio para aprender. https://www.w3schools.com/

Si intentas aplicar lo siguiente no funcionaria:
body {
color: coral;
}
p {
color: transparent;
}
Entonces no existe transparent cómo color, es cómo un string nulo en el que no hay nada mas que su referencia

Si existe en la actualidad ...

Acabo de ver en esta parte de la documentación https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.php que el background-color si que admite cómo color el transparente pero transparent no es un color cómo tal.
Así que la pregunta se responde así:
transparent no es un color pero se acepta cómo constante en los background-color de las etiquetas.


background-color: transparent;




A ver, ya te dijeron como tres veces que w3schools.com no es un sitio donde mirar documentación. Es como venir aquí y decirnos que tu amigo joselito dice que el color "miColorFavorito" no te está funcionando... la opinión de una persona no tiene sentido cuando se habla de especificaciones. Mira la documentación de la especificación, mira la mdn de mozilla (hacen un trabajo brutal documentando todo en múltiples idiomas) o mira caniuse, que suele estar siempre bien actualizado y tener información más o menos correcta.

A todo esto, afirmar "no es un color pero se acepta" es incorrecto... puesto que está definido en la especificación como named-color, ergo, es un color con nombre propio.

Recuerda que esto no es un foro. No hay un ida y vuelta, sino que eliges la respuesta que te resultó más útil. Es posible que descubras la respuesta por tu cuenta, en cuyo caso deberías publicarla y marcarla para que quede respondida y le sirva a alguien más.
